Two sets having strongly seperated points are strongly seperated themselves
Definition :- Two sets $A$ and $B$ are strongly seperated if there exist open neighbourhoods $U$ and $V$ such that $A \subseteq U , B \subseteq V , U\cap V=\phi$
Question :$A$ and $B$ are two compact subsets of a topological space $(X, \tau)$ such that each point of $A$ is strongly seperated from each point of $B$ . Prove that $A$ and $B$ are strongly seperated in $X$.
My overall Idea : Any two points from the given sets have disjoint neighbourhoods , and by taking the disjoint neighbourhoods corresponding to each point as cover for each sets, we must have a finite subcover with empty intersections.
Fix $a_o \in A , b_o \in B$ .
Then $\forall b\in B, \exists U_b  $ such that $U_{a_o} \cap U_b =\phi $
But this $U_{a_o} $  depend on the $b$ taken in $B$ .
I am not sure how to proceed further .
Any  hints. Thanks .

Hint: as a first step, prove it under the assumption that $|B| = 1$.

@Ulli  I am facing the similar problem :  Dependence of the disjoint neighbourhoods on the point in $A$ . Also arbitrary intersection of open sets may not be open .

Fix $a$ in $A$. Then for each $b$ in $B$ there exists disjoint open sets $V_b$ and $U_b$ with $a$ in $V_b$ and $b$ in $U_b$. The $U_b$'s, as $b$ ranges over $B$, form and open cover of $B$, so by compactness we can extract a finite subcover $U_b$ with $b$ varying in a finite subset $B'$ of $B$.
Now define $V$ as the intersection of the $V_b$'s as $b$ ranges in $B'$ and $U$ as the union of the $U_b$'s as $b$ ranges in $B'$. This shows that $B$ is strongly separated from points of $A$.
Now, from what we just proved, for each point $a$ in $A$ we can take disjoint open sets $W_a$ and $G_a$ with $a$ in $W_a$ and $B \subseteq G_a$. The $W_a$'s form an open cover of $A$ so by compactness exists a finite subset $A'$ of $A$ such that the $W_a$'s with $a$ in $A'$ sill form and open cover of $A$. Now define $W$ as the union of the $W_a$'s with $a$ in $A'$ and $G$ as the intersection of the $G_a$ with $a$ in $A'$. This completes the proof.
